# Propagating a Scala type parameter

Tags: scala

This is something I would think people would commonly want to do in Scala, but I'm damned if I can find even a single example anywhere.

This code doesn't compile due to type erasure, but it demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
def parse[T](json: JsValue): T = {
  json.validate[T] match {
    case JsSuccess(x, _) => x
    case JsError(errors) => throw new MyException(errors.toString)
  }
}
```

The way I've seen type information be preserved from erasure is to add an implicit `ClassTag` parameter:

```
def parse[T](json: JsValue)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): T = {
  json.validate[T] match {
    case JsSuccess(x, _) => x
    case JsError(errors) => throw new MyException(errors.toString)
  }
}
```

But...now what?  If that `validate` method took a `ClassTag` parameter I suppose I could just pass it directly:

```
json.validate(ct)
```

...but it doesn't, it takes an implicit `Reads[T]`, and I can't discern how to get from a `ClassTag[T]` to a `Reads[T]`.

Is it possible to propagate type information arbitrarily like this?  If so, how?  Or are my expectations just too high, it's not possible, and that's why I can't find any examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a type erasure problem. You can pass the type parameter `T` to `validate` and it hasn't been erased yet. The problem is that you need an implicit `Reads[T]` available in scope. You can fix this easily by adding it as a context bound:

```
def parse[T: Reads](json: JsValue): T = {
  json.validate[T] match {
    case JsSuccess(x, _) => x
    case JsError(errors) => throw new MyException(errors.toString)
  }
}
```

This de-sugars to:

```
def parse[T](json: JsValue)(implicit r: Reads[T]): T = {
  json.validate[T] match {
    case JsSuccess(x, _) => x
    case JsError(errors) => throw new MyException(errors.toString)
  }
}
```

Note that this method is more or less equivalent to writing `json.as[T]`, albeit with a different exception.

---

I suppose the source of confusion might be the error:

```
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : x.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: T
           case JsSuccess(x, _) => x
                                   ^
```

But the first error actually explains the problem:

```
<console>:15: error: No Json deserializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
         json.validate[T] match {
                      ^
```

The second error is caused by the first error (the compiler should have probably stopped there), so the second error doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Wow, that's some pretty delicious sugar!  Can you give me a pointer to where it's documented?

Comment: @Sean [Context and view bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass implicit `Reads` to parse method:

```
def parse[T:Reads](json: JsValue): T = {
  json.validate[T] match {
    case JsSuccess(x, _) => x
    case JsError(errors) => throw new MyException(errors.toString)
  }
}
```

> This code doesn't compile due to type erasure

No, if you try compile it you'll get something like: *"cannot find implicit Reads[T] for parse"*